# add subscription for stripe payment gateways for future dates

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm building stripe payment gateway in PHP, all things working. but I need to create first subscription for future dates(that user select). its always starts with current date when I submit details. Please help...

I'm not able to find there is date parameter for start subscription from specific date. Please help so I can complete payment gateway.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscriptions

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount"      => 1, 
    "currency"    => "usd",
    "customer"    => $stripe_custmerid,
    "description" => $_SESSION['user_name']
));

$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
    "customer" => $stripe_custmerid,
    "plan"     => $plan_id,
));
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to set a specified date to bill the user from the Stripe API. What you can do is create a customer on Stripe and charge their account at a later date. You'd have to implement the logic to do this. Save the card and charge it later: https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-save-a-card-and-charge-it-later

Comment: Hi Bug hunter, thanks i think it better way till stripe not add any argument. but i have some confusion like how i mange subcriptions and payment details